# Access multidimensional array with a path-like string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function called `get_config()` and an array called `$config`.

I call the function by using `get_config('site.name')` and am looking for a way to return the value of `$config` so for this example, the function should return `$config['site']['name']`.

I'm nearly pulling my hair out - trying not to use `eval()`! Any ideas?

**EDIT**: So far I have:

```
function get_config($item)
{
  global $config;

  $item_config = '';
  $item_path = ''; 

  foreach(explode('.', $item) as $item_part)
  {
    $item_path .= $item."][";

    $item = $config.{rtrim($item_path, "][")};
  }

  return $item;
}
```

Comment: show us what you have so far

Comment: Like [explode(" ")](http://www.php.net/explode) ?

Comment: Not really. I need to then use the split string to access an multi-dimensional array - which I can't seem to do with `explode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function get_config($config, $string) {
    $keys = explode('.', $string);
    $current = $config;
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if(!is_array($current) || !array_key_exists($key, $current)) {
            throw new Exception('index ' . $string . ' was not found');
        }
        $current = $current[$key];
    }
    return $current;
}
```

Comment: Yes! It works. Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as I can :D

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like...

```
function get_config($item)
{
      global $config;
      return $config[{str_replace('.','][',$item)}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your get_config function, you can parse the string using explode function in php

```
function get_config($data){
 $pieces = explode(".", $data);

 return $config[$pieces[0]][$pieces[1]];

}
```